# Using PHP CURL how to post json data with basic authentication

Tags: php, api, curl, php-curl

I want to post data using PHP curl with basic authentication. Here is my code but I am not able to post using API. But it's working with postman.

```
$urlp = "URL/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZOSA_UPLOAD_SRV/AccountOrderSet?sap-client=900";
$username = '*****';
$password = '********';


$ch = curl_init ();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$urlp);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_MUTE,1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD,"$username:$password");
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,"Proventum Proxy/1.0 (Linux)");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); //times out after 10s
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
 curl_setopt($chp, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Accept: application/json',
                'X-Requested-With: application/json')
            );
            
  if ($HTTP_REFERER) {
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER, $HTTP_REFERER);
  }
  
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$datap_string);
    
  $result = curl_exec ($ch);
  print $result;
  curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What about the code from Postman,
Did you copy the code from Postman and use it yet?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are,
add to the HTTPHEADER option:

```
Authorization: Basic base64encode(username:password)
```

for example:

```
curl_setopt($chp, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=',
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json',
            'X-Requested-With: application/json')
        );
```